# Ingesting multi-valued dimension from comma sep string

Tags: druid, data-ingestion

I have event data from Kafka with the following structure that I want to ingest in Druid

```
{
  "event": "some_event",
  "id": "1",
  "parameters": {
    "campaigns": "campaign1, campaign2",
    "other_stuff": "important_info"  
  }
}
```

Specifically, I want to transform the dimension "campaigns" from a comma-separated string into an array / multi-valued dimension so that it can be nicely filtered and grouped by.
My ingestion so far looks as follows

```
{
  "type": "kafka",
  "dataSchema": {
    "dataSource": "event-data",
    "parser": {
      "type": "string",
      "parseSpec": {
        "format": "json",
        "timestampSpec": {
          "column": "timestamp",
          "format": "posix"
        },
        "flattenSpec": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "root", 
              "name": "parameters"
            },
            {
              "type": "jq", 
              "name": "campaigns", 
              "expr": ".parameters.campaigns"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dimensionSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          "event", 
          "id", 
          "campaigns"
        ]
      }
    },
    "metricsSpec": [
      {
        "type": "count",
        "name": "count"
      }
    ],
    "granularitySpec": {
      "type": "uniform",
      ...
    }
  },
  "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "kafka",
      ...
  },
  "ioConfig": {
    "topic": "production-tracking", 
    ...  
  }  
}
```

Which however leads to campaigns being ingested as a string.
I could neither find a way to generate an array out of it with a jq expression in flattenSpec nor did I find something like a string split expression that may be used as a transformSpec.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `useFieldDiscover: false` in your ingestion spec. when this flag is set to true (which is default case) then it interprets all fields with singular values (not a map or list) and flat lists (lists of singular values) at the root level as columns.

Here is a good example and reference link to use flatten spec:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/flatten-json.html

Comment: thanks that's good to know. however the field is a string to begin with, so this unfortunately doesn't change anything..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like since Druid 0.17.0, Druid expressions support typed constructors for creating arrays, so using expression `string_to_array` should do the trick!